# Selects to Delete

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Is there any tool or easy rule to convert `SELECT` to `DELETE`? I have this `SQL SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Produkter
INNER JOIN ProduktTillhorKategori
ON Produkter.IDProdukt = ProduktTillhorKategori.IDProdukt
WHERE IDKategori = 16
```

That I want to convert into a `DELETE` (everything the `SELECT` finds in `Produkter` I want to delete)

I tried following an example but I didn't get it to work. I'm using phpmyadmin if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just change it.

```
DELETE Produkter 
    FROM Produkter
        INNER JOIN ProduktTillhorKategori
            ON Produkter.IDProdukt = ProduktTillhorKategori.IDProdukt
    WHERE IDKategori = 16
```

However, from a DB point of view, that is not good practice since you will get rows in `ProduktTillhorKategori` that points to deleted `Produkter`, so you should really delete them as well:

```
DELETE Produkter,ProduktTillhorKategori 
    FROM Produkter
        INNER JOIN ProduktTillhorKategori
            ON Produkter.IDProdukt = ProduktTillhorKategori.IDProdukt
    WHERE IDKategori = 16
```

Comment: Thankyou for not only providing an answer but also saving me from having to make another delete statement

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
DELETE Produkter FROM Produkter INNER JOIN ProduktTillhorKategori 
WHERE Produkter.IDProdukt = ProduktTillhorKategori.IDProdukt AND IDKategori = 16;
```